# Adding Meta-Data to Array Instances

Tags: java, instrumentation

I'm looking for a way to store extra Meta-Data to array instances. I have been able to realize this for standard objects by employing bytecode injection techniques to inject an extra String field directly into class file binaries.

However, in order for this strategy to work the .class file must be available for modification; Array classes in java do not have a corresponding .class file, and thus cannot be instrumented in this manor. Is there any other practicable way to accomplish this?

I would preferably like to implement this in java without having to result to modifying JVM C++ files. Aside from the extra layer of complexity this would undoubtedly add to the project, going this route would almost certainly break the much-valued portability provided by the platform.

Comment: You want to add generic instrumentation to ALL instances of array types?  That's likely not possible.

Comment: Yes, I would like to add a single additional field to all array instances. As the Array class is loaded relatively early in the JVM life-cycle, the class would obviously have to be statically instrumented and pre-pended to the boot classpath.

Comment: @kuporific yes there is in a way see my reply to Guillaume Darmont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look to [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html).

To match Map contract, you will have to define a wrapper class for your arrays that will override `equals` and `hashcode` methods.
Then you define a meta-data object to handle your custom properties.

The prototype would be :

```
WeakHashMap<ArrayWrapper,MetaData> map;
map.put(new ArrayWrapper(primitiveArray), new MetaData("string1",...));
```

Comment: This type of solution may have to do. I'm building a platform that attaches to the JVM process and then proceeds to  intercept/instrument requests to access memory. Now this all has to happen transparently to the application developer. By introducing new wrapper instances into the object graph this makes that a little harder to accomplish but not impossible I guess. So to be clear you think there is no way to store additional data directly to the array class?